# Click Selenium href link

Tags: python, selenium

I have a Selenium element with `href="/daVinci/sys/systems/SK419114/dvmt`

[image]

I am trying to click on it and go to the next page, my line of code is:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_texrt(" ").click()
```

So, what should be in the link text in the double quote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find element by link text wont work in this case as you need to know the text for that element like the below example :

```html
 <a href="continue.html">Continue</a>
```

where the following code will work but in your case you do not have such a text based link:

```py
driver.find_element_by_link_texrt("Continue").click()
```

For your case can use this:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="/daVinci/sys/systems/SK419114/dvmt"').click();
```

Comment: Your answer is correct :) but you need some markdown formatting. Here is a article on how to do that: https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'daVinci/sys/systems')]").click()
```

Comment: Hi itronic1990, thanks very much for your answer; however, I am still getting the "unable to locate element" error.

Comment: I have a couple question: (1) SK319114 is a system name, and as I test multiple system, can I use something like : driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'daVince/sys/systems'+args.system+'/dvmt')]").click(). where the args.system is the variable of system name

Comment: (2) what if I just use "driver.get(full_url) to get to that page. Will this also work to get to the next page

Comment: Once again, really appreciate your help.

Comment: did you check if the element you are trying to access is inside a frame? Through automation you are trying to simulate the manual process you follow. so driver.get(full_url) couldnt be a ideal solution

Comment: there was a spelling mistake in the code. Corrected it now. See if that works

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the same with explicit wait :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, '/daVinci/sys/systems')]"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```